# MongoDB failIndexKeyTooLong

Tags: mongodb

I have a hard time understanding if the failIndexKeyTooLong parameter is for all collections, or if there is a way to set it up for only some collections?

I am reading the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/parameters/#param.failIndexKeyTooLong

I think it is for all collections (indexes) in the database, but I cannot read it, and be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [server parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/parameters/#param.failIndexKeyTooLong) and applies to all collections. You run this command:

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand( { setParameter: 1, failIndexKeyTooLong: false } )
```

Which essentially "downgrades" the server in terms of handling that use case to version `2.4` where this was allowed behavior.